# How to initialize generic parameter type T?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Simple question:
If you have a `string x`, to initialize it you simple do one of the following:

```
string x = String.Empty;
```

or

```
string x = null;
```

What about Generic parameter T?

I've tried doing:

```
void someMethod<T>(T y)
{
    T x = new T();  
    ...
}
```

Generate error :
**Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint**

Comment: Why do you want to do it at the position where you don't know the type?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have two options:

You can constrain T: you do this by adding: `where T : new()` to your method. Now you can only use the `someMethod` with a type that has a parameterless, default constructor (see [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)).

Or you use `default(T)`. For a reference type, this will give `null`. But for example, for an integer value this will give `0` (see [default Keyword in Generic Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx)).

Here is a basic console application that demonstrates the difference:

```
using System;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        public static T SomeNewMethod<T>()
            where T : new()
        {
            return new T();
        }

        public static T SomeDefaultMethod<T>()
            where T : new()
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        struct MyStruct { }

        class MyClass { }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunWithNew();
            RunWithDefault();
        }

        private static void RunWithDefault()
        {
            MyStruct s = SomeDefaultMethod<MyStruct>();
            MyClass c = SomeDefaultMethod<MyClass>();
            int i = SomeDefaultMethod<int>();
            bool b = SomeDefaultMethod<bool>();

            Console.WriteLine("Default");
            Output(s, c, i, b);
        }

        private static void RunWithNew()
        {
            MyStruct s = SomeNewMethod<MyStruct>();
            MyClass c = SomeNewMethod<MyClass>();
            int i = SomeNewMethod<int>();
            bool b = SomeNewMethod<bool>();

            Console.WriteLine("New");
            Output(s, c, i, b);
        }

        private static void Output(MyStruct s, MyClass c, int i, bool b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("s: " + s);
            Console.WriteLine("c: " + c);
            Console.WriteLine("i: " + i);
            Console.WriteLine("b: " + b);
        }

    }
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
New
s: Stackoverflow.Program+MyStruct
c: Stackoverflow.Program+MyClass
i: 0
b: False
Default
s: Stackoverflow.Program+MyStruct
c:
i: 0
b: False
```

Comment: Also, if you have `where T : struct` then `T t = new T();` is allowed and produces the same value as `default(T)`. If you have the constraint `where U : class`, then `U u = null;` is allowed and equivalent to `default(U)`. The constraint `where U : new()` can be combined with `class` but not with `struct`.

Comment: Years later.... this works fine if your Type is a numeric primitive type. They have default constructors that generate zero default values.

Answer (score 14):

use `default` keyword.

```
T x = default(T);
```

See: [default Keyword in Generic Code (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Given a variable t of a parameterized type T, the statement t = null
>   is only valid if T is a reference type and t = 0 will only work for
>   numeric value types but not for structs. The solution is to use the
>   default keyword, which will return null for reference types and zero
>   for numeric value types. For structs, it will return each member of
>   the struct initialized to zero or null depending on whether they are
>   value or reference types.

Answer (score 9):

You need to add a `new` constraint for the type parameter `T`.

```
void someMethod<T>(T y) where T : new()
{
    T x = new T();  
    ...
}
```

This will only be valid for types with a default constructor however.

The `where` clause for `T` is a [generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). In this case, it requires that any type `T` this method is applied to must have a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: "because it does not have the new() constraint" => add the `new()` constraint. Simples :)

Comment: @Lee default and _parameterless_ :D

Comment: Can you please explain what happenes behind th scene with the `where:` syntax?

Comment: @JavaSa [Here's a good place to start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: @JavaSa - I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

If you really need an instance of T and not a default null value for reference types, use:

```
Activator.CreateInstance()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `default` construct to set it to whatever that Type's default is.

The default keyword allows you to tell the compiler that at compile time the default value of this variable should be used. If the type argument supplied is a numeric value (e.g., int, long, decimal), then the default value is zero. If the type argument supplied is a reference type, then the default value is null. If the type argument supplied is a struct, then the default value of the struct is determined by initializing each member field of the struct to zero for numeric types or null for reference types.

Use something like :

`T data = default(T);`

For details, read : [Initializing Generic Variables to Their Default Values](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Generics_Recipes%E2%80%94Initializing_Generic_Variables_to_Their_Default_Values)